# Trying To Display Number Of times each option is selected using an array

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a code which displays the sum of number of times each option is selected using an array

However whenever I run this code the array resets all elements to zero after running the code the second time

```
let arr = [0,0,0,0]

const poll = { 
    registerNewAnswer: function(a)
    {
        return prompt(`
            Which is your favourite Movie?
            0: Toy Story
            1: Star Wars
            2: Fast & Furious
            3: Final Destination
            (Write option number)
        `);
    }
}

let b = poll.registerNewAnswer(); 
console.log(b);
for(let [i,j] of arr.entries())
{
    if (i==b)
    {
        arr[i]=(arr[i]+1);
    };
}
console.log(...arr);
```

Comment: There's no need for a loop. Just `arr[b]++`

Comment: Why doees `registerNewAnswer()` take an `a` parameter that it never uses?

Comment: This would only reset the counts to 0 if you execute the `let arr = [0,0,0,0]` line again. That shouldn't be in the loop.

Comment: Nope it isn't its kept outside the object and the loop for initialization purposes

Comment: Then I don't see why it would reset to 0. They should only be initialized when you first load the script.

Comment: "Number of options each item is selected" how do you call registerNewAnswer multiple times? Refreshing the page, clicking a button? loop?

Comment: refreshing the page

Comment: @Hitesh You will need to use localStorage to save your values. The moment you refresh the page, the javascript session is destroyed

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the entries somewhere, otherwise your first line will always reset `arr` to zero. I suggest localStorage for this example. Could also be a call out to an API for database storage.

In the code below- it first checks for the existence of the localStorage.arr.

Then, if it is null, it creates an empty array and saves it for next time.

Also, b isn't necessary, you can just add it to the array with `arr[]`.

```js
let arr = localStorage.getItem('arr');
if (!arr) {
    arr = [];
    localStorage.setItem('arr', arr);
}

const poll = { 
    registerNewAnswer: function()
    {
        return prompt(`
            Which is your favourite Movie?
            0: Toy Story
            1: Star Wars
            2: Fast & Furious
            3: Final Destination
            (Write option number)`);
    }
}

arr.push(poll.registerNewAnswer()); 
console.log(poll.registerNewAnswer);
for(let [i,j] of arr.entries())
{
    if (i==b)
    {
    arr[i]=(arr[i]+1);
    };
}
console.log(...arr);
```

Comment: `arr[] = poll.registerNewAnswer();` - syntax error, that looks like a PHP-style assignment.

Comment: There still seems to be an error on the localStorage.setItem('arr'); line regarding number of argumemnts

Comment: yes. this is just quick pseudocode to share the idea. Sorry about that. Should I just delete it?